# JSON.stringify - Strange behaviour with backslash in array

Tags: javascript, json

I was playing with JS while I noticed a strange behaviour with backslash `\` inserted into a string within an array printed using `JSON.stringify()`. Of course the backslash is used to escaping special chars, but what happens if we need to put backslash in a string? Just use backslash to escape itself you're thinking, but it doesn't work with JSON.stringify

**This should print one backslash**

```js
array = ['\\'];
document.write(JSON.stringify(array));
```

**This should print two backslashes**

```js
array = ['\\\\'];
document.write(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Am I missing something? Could be that considered as a bug of JSON.stringify?

Comment: JSON.stringify is escaping the backslashes you already have.

Comment: "This should print one backslash" --- it should not

Comment: So how can I print a single backslash with JSON.stringify? Of course `array = ['\'];` will fail with an unterminated string..

Comment: The backslash is also the escape character in JSON. See http://json.org, string. `"\"` would be invalid JSON, since it is an unterminated string. I'm not sure where your confusing comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct. `JSON.stringify` will return the required string to recreate that object - as your string requires that you escape a backslash, it will also return the required escape backslash to generate the string properly.

Try this:

```
array = ['\\'];
var x = JSON.stringify(array)
var y = JSON.parse(x)
if (array[0] == y[0]) alert("it works")
```

or

```
array = ['\\'];
if (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))[0] == array[0]) alert("it really works")
```